# Django, how to get count of cities of a country in two seperate models

Tags: django

I have 2 related models like this:

```
class Countries(models.Model):
    country= models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, verbose_name='country')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.country

class Cities(models.Model):
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=60,blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='name of the city' )
    Rightful_owner = models.ManyToManyField(Countries, verbose_name='the country name', related_name='Rightful')
```

Now I want to make an html table and write how many cities each country has? like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XpazG.png)

what should I do in view.py and the html pages?

I need the cod which I have to write in view.py and the html pages

Comment: A `City` can belong to multiple `Countries`?

Answer (score 4):

The modeling looks *odd*: you model this with a [**`ManyToManyField`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField), this means that a `City` can related to zero, one and more `Country`s.

If you want to keep the modeling, you can [**`.annotate(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#annotate) with:

```
from django.db.models import Count

Countries.objects.annotate(ncities=Count('Rightful'))
```

The `Countries` objects that arise from this `QuerySet` will have an extra attribute `.ncities` with the number of `cities` that have this as (one of the) `Countries`.

---

> **Note**: normally a Django model is given a *singular* name, so `Country` instead of <s>`Countries`</s>.